# Labels inside <input> tags

Tags: html

Ok, so I seen this on one of my applications I just bought and now I am wanting to do it with my forms. It appears the labels are actually inside the inputs.

**http://i1309.photobucket.com/albums/s627/mievan123/This_zps1884e41d.png**

I know you can use placeholders but they disapear once you start typing in the field. I want it to stay like the image above. I typed "Mr." before I took the picture in the Title field.

What's the secret!!!!

```
label {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #669244;
    background: #669244;
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 11px 10px;
}
input {
    border: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #669244;
}

textarea { 
    border: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #669244;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the application you bought?  Should be pretty easy to figure out what they're doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surround the `input` element with another element that has the border and the "label" and remove the border from the `input`.

```
label {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: gray;
    padding: 5px;
}
input {
    border: 0;
    color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/JjasN/1/

Comment: Wow! Great solution and fast response. Thank you very much! It isn't a required thing but it will be cool to try out! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: What about a <textarea> ??

Comment: @MitchEvans should work more or less the same I think; just add `textarea` to the stylesheet rules

Comment: I edited my question to include what I have. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MitchEvans practically yes, but you can include those rules in the same ruleset as `input` as in `input, textarea {`

Comment: Ok, because this is what I am getting: https://www.green-panda.com/forms/my_panda_registration_form_2.html

Comment: You will have to hit Next to see it

Comment: @MitchEvans not sure exactly how you want this to look, but at least for the `<label>` that wraps the textarea add `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`